# how can I update all application

Tags: android

I want to update all applications on the system with one button on the my application. My application can use sudo. I also know, from Linux, the system can be updated with sudo command. So, Is it possible that I can update all applications on the system with one button? If yes, how ?

Comment: "the system can be updated with sudo command" -- The `sudo` doesn't do anything by itself, it only allows you to run commands as root.

Comment: @aioobe is it possible with other way ?

Comment: No, not that I know of at least.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo su apt-get update 

sudo su apt-get upgrade
```

try these both so that your system can be updated easily.

Comment: do I need put some permission

Comment: no friend if u use sudo no probs . u have to give the install time password for sudo

Comment: but the question is tagged android. Android doesn't use apt.